# Voice of early mathematicians

Tags: soft-question, math-history

Do we have voice/film recordings of earlier mathematicians?

While teaching or lecturing may be... after invention of the phonograph?

Comment: See [this Math Overflow posting](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/58554/preferably-rare-audio-video-recordings-of-famous-mathematicians) and replies.

Comment: Ah, thanks.. shall go through.